# What does echo <<<output do?

Tags: php, html, echo

I came across some code in a file I was working that basically has

```
echo <<<output

"some html here"

output;
```

What does this do?  Normally I do something like

```
echo "some html here";
```

but I've run into some cases where I have to use both ' and " and then it breaks the statement to echo, I think the first method would be a way around this but I would like to know what it's actually doing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Great, thank you! I was googling with the word output as I thought this was part of the syntax but apparently it doesn't matter what word you use.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) notation.

> A third way to delimit strings is the heredoc syntax: <<<. After this operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline. The string itself follows, and then the same identifier again to close the quotation.